Can't I create Windows 10 VM on Azure
I am trying to create an Microsoft Windows 10 Azure VM. I am using Azure for Students Subscription. Everytime I try creating it, I get the error that the VM image is not available. I have used the command
az vm list-skus --location eastus --size Standard_DS1_v2 --all --output table

az vm list-skus --location eastus --size Standard_D2as_v4 --all --output table

To confirm that it's available in the region. Can some help me out here.
The requested VM size for resource 'Following SKUs have failed for Capacity 
Restrictions: Standard_D2as_v4' is currently not available in location 
'eastus'. Please try another size or deploy to a different location or 
different zone. See https://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable for details.

$ az vm list-skus --location eastus --size Standard_D2as_v4 --all --output table

ResourceType     Locations    Name              Zones    Restrictions
---------------  -----------  ----------------  -------  --------------
virtualMachines  eastus       Standard_D2as_v4  1,2,3    None

$ az vm list-skus --location eastus --size Standard_DS1_v2 --all --output table
ResourceType     Locations    Name             Zones    Restrictions
---------------  -----------  ---------------  -------  --------------
virtualMachines  eastus       Standard_DS1_v2  1,2,3    None


Hi @ SMTPKING.   The Standard_D2as_v4 size is not available in the East US region for your subscription. You can check using the command: Get-AzVMSize -Location 'eastus' | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Standard_D2as_v4" } You can use another location to create a VM.

@VenkatV, I edited the question to show the result of the search

Why are you creating v4 instead of latest v5? And keep in mind your error doesn't have anything to do with Windows 10, it's all about the specific size that you chose.

@mason anyone that allows me to use Windows 10 in eastus with Azure Students subscription is fine by me.

You can check your subscription's current quota for VM cores in East US and make sure it aligns with your chosen VM sizes. This can be done using az vm list-usage --location eastus --output table and Students subscriptions may have additional restrictions on VM sizes and availability.


Can't I create Windows 10 VM on Azure

The requested VM size for resource 'Following SKUs have failed for Capacity 
Restrictions: Standard_D2as_v4' is currently not available in location 
'eastus'.

The error you encountered is due to the specified SKU (Standard Dv4 Family vCPUs) not being available in your subscription. You can check the available CPU quota for your subscription using the command below:
  az vm list-usage --location eastus --output table

Output:


Note: Azure student subscriptions may have additional restrictions on VM sizes and availability

If D-Series v4 CPU's are not available, make sure to select another series.

Reference: Choose the Azure account that’s right for you
